# Как вставить определенный тег внутри текста?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

К примеру у меня есть тег с текстом.

```
<span>robert.smith888@gmail.com</span>
```

И он не помещается в свой блок и я хочу при определенной ширине экрана **добавить и удалить** тег br перед словом robert.smith чтобы осталные слова (888@gmail.com) начинались с новой строки.

```
let addingAdditionalTag = () => {
  let widthForTag = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  let brTag = document.createElement("br");
  if (widthForTag > 768) {
    //но вот тут незнаю как правильно добавить тег внутри текста
  }
 }
```

Comment: приведите пример элемента span который хотите получить на выходе

Comment: @yolosora прочитайте внимательно пожалуйста там есть пример.И ответ уже дан на данный вопрос.

Comment: если добавить и удалить тег br как вы пишите, то ничего не произойдет

Comment: @yolosora кстати добавление есть а удаление нету :( нет добавляем при определенной ширине скажем больше 765 пикселей удаляем при меньше ширины 765 пикселей.

Comment: так а в каком месте вставлять перенос? посл определенного количества символов? перед цифрами?

Comment: @yolosora  И он не помещается в свой блок и я хочу при определенной ширине экрана добавить и удалить тег br перед словом robert.smith чтобы осталные слова (888@gmail.com) начинались с новой строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//if (widthForTag > 768) {
  const span = document.querySelector('span');
  span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replace(/^([^\d]+)(.*)$/, '$1<br/>$2');
//}
```

```html
<span>robert.smith888@gmail.com</span>
```

Comment: спасибо.Если можно обясните пожалуйста что за символы вы там используете и зачем? @Darth

Comment: Я не стал заморачиваться и воспользовался [регулярным выражением](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript)

Comment: спасибо огромное @Darth